# Automatically check box false when reach completion date, any solution there?

Tags: checkbox

I have a check- box called "Active" and other fields called "completion date" with a date picker when the completion date is completed or end, automatically the Active check box should be disabled or false. there is any solution there?

Comment: Please use only relevant tags. This question is not related to `salesforcedx`. Please also make an effort to include your work or research so far in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to implement it through a `schedulable interface` that executes in a specific time interval & updates the field.

Basically, a class that implements the Schedulable interface.

```
    global class MySchedulableClass implements Schedulable {
     public static String cron= '0 00 01 * * ?';  //Every Day at 1 AM

    // Call this method to Schedule your class
    global static String scheduleMe() {
      MySchedulableClass sc = new MySchedulableClass();
       return System.schedule('Schedule MySchedulableClass everyday at 1 am' + '-' + System.now() + System.currentTimeMillis(), cron, sc);
    }
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {...} //put the logic to check completion date here
   }
```

You can read more about schedulable class [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)..

Or if the object is updated often. You can put a condition to set the field value to false.

Update: You can create a Process builder too. Make sure the Criteria is set to `When the record is created` else Scheduled Actions won't be available.

Comment: It is not possible in process builder @Sachin

Comment: There isn't any OOTB functionality to schedule Process builders.

Comment: That's not quite right. Process Builder [does support scheduled actions](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_builder).

Comment: This seems to fulfil the OP use case. *PS:* `Scheduled actions` are available only on `record create`.